# Joining Tables in UI Component Collection

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent

My goal is to join another (custom) table to the collection of the customer list ui component in adminhtml and by that add a condition which customers are shown.

What is the best (or any way) to do that?

I ve tried preferences for the DataProvider `Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider` as well as the Grid Collection `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection`.
But they didnt work, because from what i ve seen, those classes are instantiated with `new XYZ` via Object Manager.

I tried changing the used collection via .xml in `di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customer_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">MYCUSTOM\MODULE\..\Customer\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

I ran out of ideas to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a solution which might be work for you.

At this case, I am doing below  step to add a custom table  with customer grid

### Step1: Change the Data source class from UI Collection factory:

Instead of  Changes data source class of `customer_listing_data_source` from  di.xml(`<item name="customer_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">MYCUSTOM\MODULE\..\Customer\Grid\Collection</item>`)

I have using plugin  around method  over class `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory`

Have changed `GetReport()` method output using own grid collection class.

**di.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin disabled="false" 
                        name="StackExchange_Magento_Plugin_Magento_Framework_View_DesignInterface" 
                        sortOrder="10" type="StackExchange\Magento\Plugin\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactoryPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**And Plugin Class:**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Plugin\UiComponent\DataProvider;
/**
 * Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection
 */
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class CollectionFactoryPlugin {

    /**
     * @var Collection[]
     */
    protected $collections;

    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManagerInterface
     * @param array $collections
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManagerInterface,
        array $collections = []
    ) {
        $this->collections = $collections;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManagerInterface;
    }
    public function aroundGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $requestName
    )
    {
     if($requestName !== 'customer_listing_data_source') 
     {
         return $proceed($requestName);
     }


        $collection = $this->objectManager->create(\StackExchange\Magento\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Customer\Collection::CLASS);
        if (!$collection instanceof Collection) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('%s is not of Collection type.', $requestName));
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

### Steps2: Create grid Collection which is a replica of original Class

Create a grid collection class `StackExchange\Magento\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Customer` which is replica of original grid class `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection`

And that new Class on `_initSelect()` add the custom table with Magento Collection class.

And after that, i have to map the field of the custom fields to  `$_map`  variable, So that error does not occur during filter.

```
 protected $_map = ['fields' => 
        ['entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id'],
        'total_qty' => 'testorder.total_qty' // Custom table field
        ];
```

**New grid Class**

```
<?php


namespace StackExchange\Magento\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Customer;


use Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Document;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected $document = Document::class;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected $_map = ['fields' => 
        ['entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id'],
        'total_qty' => 'testorder.total_qty'
        ];

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param Logger $logger
     * @param FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy
     * @param EventManager $eventManager
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param string $resourceModel
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'customer_grid_flat',
        $resourceModel = \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer::class
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }
    protected function _initSelect() {

        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['salesorder' => $this->getTable('testorder')], 
                'salesorder.customer_id = main_table.entity_id',
                ['total_qty']
        );
        return $this;
    }
    protected function _initInitialFieldsToSelect() {
        parent::_initInitialFieldsToSelect();
    }

}
```

### Next step: add the custom field to customer_listing.xml

the last step add your field to  *`app/code/vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns">
        <column name="total_qty">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Total</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this too. I think there should be a better way to do something like this by default. But apparently there isnt. So im going this way.